# Drupal custom theme visibility to all users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-navigation

I'm creating a custom drupal 7 theme

```
<?php print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-headermenu'), 'attributes' => array('class'=> array('links', 'headermenu')) )); ?>
```

Above is the code I'm using in my theme to show a menu I created using the Admin section.

My problem is the menu is getting displayed only for the Admin.

I want it to be shown to anonymous as well as registered users.

Also, I've tried changing the role permission by ticking 'Administer Block' and 'Administer menus and menu items' to all the three kind of users. Nothing helps.

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this will answer your question, because it side steps the code above - but, you could try enabling the [Menu Block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, then using it to create a *block* based on your desired menu. Then you can place it any block region, and control it via the normal block controls.

The only trick of it is you might need to add a region to your template if it doesn't exist in the place that you want, but that's easy.

Comment: I tried a lot and found, it's my silly mistake. The link for the menus I added points node/add.

And I'm not providing the permission to create post except admin.

Fixed now, Thanks a lot man.